# jquery .off doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'll be short: jquery `.off()` doesn't disable a listen I've set with `.on`.

html:

```
<span id="myspan">lol</span>
<button id="b1">jquery On</button>
<button id="b2">jquery Off</button>
```

js:

```
$("#b1").on("click", add);
$("#b2").on("click", del);

function add() {
    $("#myspan").on("click", function(e) {
        var a = 1;
        testfunc(a, e);
    });
}

function del() {
    $("#myspan").off("click", testfunc);
}

function testfunc(num, event) {
   alert(num);
}
```

So first we add to **myspan** the `testfunc()` by clicking the *jquery On* button. After we do that, if we click on the span, we get an alert. Next, we click the *jquery off* button. That is supposed to remove the listener but it doesn't. Even after that, when we click on **myspan** `testfunc` is still attached.

Why? And how can I remove it ?

Comment: look here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ and http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Your parameters don't match

It doesn't because you bound to a different function (anonymous one). And then you're trying to unbind from `testfunc`... In order for your event (un)binding to work **both parameters between `on` and `off` must match**.

### Possible workaround

If this is the only `click` event listener on the element, then it's be easiest way to unbind from your anonymous function by calling:

```
$("#myspan").off("click");
```

If you're binding several event handlers to click event on the same element then you can also distinguish them by providing namespaces and then use proper namespacing in `off` call.

```
$("#myspan").on("click.test", function(e) { ... });
...
$("#myspan").off("click.test");
```

Or use just namespace if you'd like to unbind several different event handlers that were bound using the same namespace:

```
$("#myspan").off(".test");
```

Comment: Right... the callback that you pass into `on` must be the same as `off`.

Comment: i use something like this $(document).off().on(" ...  
It work for me.

Answer (score 11):

You're not binding the event handler to `testfunc`, you're binding it to an anonymous function, and whitin that function you're just calling `testfunc`, so you can't automatically unbind that.

It's either

```
$("#myspan").on("click", testfunc); // bind function
```

and then

```
$("#myspan").off("click", testfunc); // unbind function
```

or to unbind the anonymous function, just

```
$("#myspan").off("click"); // remove all handlers
```

or you can also namespace the handler

```
$("#myspan").on("click.test", function(e) {
    var a = 1;
    testfunc(a, e);
});
```

and to remove only that handler

```
$("#myspan").off("click.test");
```

Answer (score 2):

In this simple case, replace your `off` call with this:

```
function del() {
    $("#myspan").off("click");
}
```

You don't need to pass the handler function to the `off` call, and if you do, it will only remove that particular handler. However, you did not attach `testfunc`, but an anonymous function that just calls `testfunc()`. Therefore, your `off` call does nothing.

Also, you never assigned the variable `testfunc`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the above solutions worked because the event listener was set on an element with onclick attribute. for unbinding the event I couldn't use off or unbind or something like that. I had to use removeAttr. and it worked for me.