# How to correctly unbind an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my bind code:

```
<div id="exam-passing-test">
    <button id="button-next-task">
       <div class="e-div-nextpage-style">'.$butText.'</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

```js
    function($){
              $.event.special.destroyed = {
                remove: function(o) {
                  if (o.handler) {
                    o.handler()
                  }
                }
              }
            })(jQuery);

            $("#exam-passing-test").on("destroyed", function() {
                console.log("bind")
                alert("Error");
            });

    $("#button-next-task").on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#exam-passing-test").off("destroyed", function() {
                console.log("unbindOk")  
            });
            $("#content-exam").load("/exam.php?action=show&epage=task&categoryId=" + selectedCategoryId, {testData:testData});
    )};
```

Ok, now i just try to do that, I simplified the code, but off still not working. Need to off() event on click button.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using `bind()` at all as it's deprecated. Use `on()` and ensure you're using an up to date version of jQuery. Secondly, `off()` is what you need to use. If it doesn't work for you, please provide a much clearer example of the issue.

Comment: `bind` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7.  Use `.on` and `.off`.

Comment: *"When i click on button i need unbind that element"* - sounds like you want `.one()`  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @freedomn-m I need unbind when I click on the button, in other cases this should work

Comment: why don't you provide a real and functional example of what you have and what you are trying to do? Because looking right now, it seems that you are trying to solve a problem using the wrong function... Read [mcve]

Comment: @CalvinNunes now I simplified the code, but still off() not working.

Comment: It is a problem with the handler on the off function because it has to be the same than the one in the on function or nothing. Remove it and try: $("#exam-passing-test").off("destroyed"); Also, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067306/323149

Comment: @JaviMollá i tried it, and also just $("#exam-passing-test").off();

Comment: @antihawk1q the point is not to simplify the code, is to show us what you are trying to do. Use a jsFiddle or Snippet... maybe you can solve this using another idea instead of `off`, but we don't know what and why you are trying this. Edit the question, add **details** to it and most important, a snippet

Comment: @CalvinNunes I'm just trying to delete event from element. Thats all. I want to add event with on() and delete with off(). The question is how to do it

Comment: Well, if you don't make an effort to elucidate the entire context of the question, then keep trying by yourself, I'm here trying to help, but I asked two times for a better context, details and snippet. If you don't provide an edit, you'll still have no answer. Just saying "I want to unbind" doesn't help much

Comment: @CalvinNunes edited. I added full code. But i dont know how its help you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [jQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```
$( "#exam-passing-test" ).one( "click", function( event ) {
  alert( "A click event happened!" );
});
```

It will handle your `click` event just once.

Comment: when I leave the page should be alert, but when I leave the page at the click of a button it should not be alert (i need unbind that)